# How to permanently delete pages I have already trashed?

Tags: comments

Months ago I deleted some of my wordpress pages including http://officeaccord.com/buy-sell/.

Every so often, I receive comments from people (mainly people trying to sell me their service) on this non-existent page. According to my Moz.com account, these non-existent pages are also still being tracked which may be hurting my google search score.

How can I locate these non-existent pages which I already deleted (they are not in my Trash folder) and ultimately, remove them permanently from my site so I stop getting these comments and avoid negative google crawl results?

Comment: If you can enter the page and it doesn't throw 404 then it means you haven't really deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

On the 'Page' admin page, you can search for content inside a page, which might be helpful if you have lots of pages.

But, if you first log in as admin, then go to the URLs that aren't supposed to be there (but are, assuming they don't "404"), then you can use the 'Edit' button on the Admin bar at the top of the page to edit that page, trashing it. You could also change the status of the page to 'private', then trash it.

It may be that people are finding the pages via the googles, so you might consider updating your search XML file.  You could also ask the googles to remove the pages from your site's search results.